# how to call plugin reactively in meteor js

Tags: jquery, meteor

i have a song plugin [html5 jquery music player](http://www.codebasehero.com/2011/07/html5-music-player-updated/) which take song names from the data base. i instantiated it inside the Template.onRendered as it is recommended. and its is working but its not reactive. so if i add new songs it will not appeared inside the play list.

the template code:

```
<template name="mysongs">
 <!--items here appears reactively
 {{#each allsongs}}
    {{songurl}} 
 {{/each}}-->
  <!--playlist of player plugin is not reactive -->
  <div class="music-player-list"></div>
</template>
```

the on created section

```
Template.mysongs.onCreated(function(){
 this.subscribe("songs");
});
```

the on rendered section

```
  Template.mysongs.onRendered(function(){
  $('.music-player-list').ttwMusicPlayer(Session.get("myPlaylist"), {
   currencySymbol:'$',
   buyText:'BUY',
   tracksToShow:3,
   autoplay:false,
   ratingCallback:function(index, playlistItem, rating){
    //some logic to process the rating, perhaps through an ajax call
   }
 });
```

the template helper

```
Template.mysongs.Helpers(
allsongs : function(){
var mysongs = songs.find({}).fetch();
mysongs.forEach(function(song){
myPlaylist.push({"id":song._id, 
                 "title" : song.songname ,
                 "cover":'1.jpg' ,
                 "duration" : song.duration, 
                 "rating":5,
                 "mp3": song.songurl,
                 "buy":'#',
                 "artist":'Alexandra'});
console.log(song._id + "  " +song.songname + " " + song.songurl);
});
Session.set("myPlaylist", myPlaylist);
console.log("myPlaylist session"+Session.get("myPlaylist")); //reactively
return Session.get("myPlaylist");
```

});

the template events

```
Template.mysongs.events({
 'click: .uploadbutton' : function(){
  // get the song object
  //save into database  
  });
```

Thanks